# Coredata best practice for associating an image with a record

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am working on an iPhone app and have an entity set up in coredata that has two attributes

- text
- order

The user can take a photo for each object in the entity.  As a proof of concept, I am saving the photo using the entites 'text' attribute in the documents folder.

I tried getting the object ID using: `[object objectID]`, but that gives me a string full of guff, eg:

`<x-coredata://791282FC-9A08-451F-9348-1B972E8A144D/Articulation/p5>`

My idea was to add another attribute 'id' to the entity that autoincrements and use that id as the filename of the photo (there will only ever be one photo per entity).

Is that considered bad practice? And if so, what should I be doing?

Thanks,
James.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an attribute `imageFileName` in the entity, and store the file name of the image there.

That way, you can implement what you want to do now (by autogenerating `imageFileName` by incrementing an internal counter),
or you can let the user name the image, if you later change your mind.

It is non-trivial to change the CoreData schema once you ship your app. So I prefer to keep a bit of room in the schema so that I can change the behavior of the program without changing the schema.

Comment: I agree with this solution although I would use a GUID as the filename instead of trying to increment a value since Core Data does not support auto-incrementing values.  Lastly, when you store the file name, make sure it is relative to the application path instead of an absolute path as the applications' directory name can and does change.

Comment: I think I'll go with this solution.  I'll save the file name in the entity in case I need to change how the app works in the future, and I'll use some sort of unique id instead of an auto increment.  Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. I'd consider creating some sort of uniqueId property that you can use to identify the object as well as generate filenames etc.

Here's a link with a previous question that can point you in the right diretion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005688/how-to-auto-increment-reference-number-persistently-when-nsmanagedobjects-created